# Why do my tests pass even though the method it tests has no code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, tdd, rspec3

I feel like I may have written these tests wrong, in the sense that they do too much. They work and pass when I run `rspec`, even though the method is empty.

Here is my spec - `invitations_controller_spec.rb`

```
describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when invited user IS an existing user' do
        before :each do
          @users = [
            create(:user),
            create(:user),
            create(:user)
          ]
        end

        it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do
          login_user
          post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
          invited_user = @users.select { |u| u[:email] == controller.params[:email] }
          expect(invited_user.first).to be_a(User)
        end
    end    
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
def create

end
```

When I run `rspec`, I get this:

```
Users::InvitationsController
  POST #create
    checks to see if invited user is an existing user
```

All green. I am glad it passes, but I feel like I approached this TDD thing wrong.

Or should I now be doing something else to now make them fail, and then add the code that makes it pass?

Comment: well, you are not using/checking anything coming from the request. You could remove login and post lines: you're just playing with your local variables

Comment: @apneadiving That's what I am thinking. How might I modify this to do that?

Comment: Rather than your users create, you can use factory girls create_list => `create_list(:user, 3)`

Comment: @japed `create(:users)` is a factory girl function. That doesn't help me with this specific problem though. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: the point is you should maybe sent a 4xx whenever the guy is already invited, so basically check the response

Comment: So if the user is already an existing user, it should respond with an HTTP code, that's what you're saying? I guess the issue with that is that this is just 1 small section of the entire controller (perhaps 2 lines). So I don't want it to actually send the response yet.

Comment: @apneadiving - I am re-reading your first comment and I am actually checking something coming from the request. Specifically this line: `invited_user = @users.select { |u| u[:email] == controller.params[:email] }`. The `post` before it, creates the test request, and then this line extracts the value from the `params` of the request.

Comment: ah yes, but you send it, its not something the controller does

Comment: Right...so how do I re-write this so that the test expects the `Create` action from the controller to send it?

Comment: @marcamillion, `create_list` is also a factory girl function.  I know it's not helping your issue, but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
invited_user = @users.select { |u| u[:email] == controller.params[:email] }
expect(invited_user.first).to be_a(User)
```

Here's your problem: @users is being set in your test setup (before-block)
So you're basically asserting that the user is in the collection of created users (@users), which is obviously the case.

A more correct approach would be to check the response-Object for the user or check the assigned instance variable within the controller (you can do this using the assigns-method, more [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs)

Comment: So if I use an instance variable (within the controller), will it find the user created in the `before` block at the beginning of the spec? I guess that's what I am a little confused about. I used FactoryGirl to create the fake user records within the spec. If I then pass the response to the controller, will it hit my test db?

Comment: Oh not quite, but you're on the right track. You have to differentiate between instance variables within your test (@users) and instance variables assigned by your controller (e.g. 'assigns(:user)'). The controller does not know of @users. You do not pass the response to the controller, but you query the controller by using post :create, which then sets the response-variable in your test, that's the one you want to check for correctness then.

Comment: Ahh ok. That makes sense. Are controller helper methods not available when I run rspec? I just got an error that it can't find a method I have defined in my `app/helpers/users/invitations_helper.rb`.

Comment: I think they might not be there, yes. If you totally need them, you can still require them though.

Comment: So what's the best place to store them? In a concern within the `app/controllers` folder?

Comment: Actually got it. Yes....the best place is to store it within `app/controllers/concerns`. Thanks!

Comment: You can also throw methods as protected in the bottom of the controller if it's not too many